# Why collection methods like add(Object o),remove (Object o) don't work inside an iteration to remove or update?

Tags: java, iterator

I have to check whether a number is even or not in an `ArrayList` collection from 0-10 numbers.  Using an `Iterator`, I have to print all even numbers inside that `ArrayList` and remove odd numbers from the `ArrayList`.

```
package hemantdhanuka;

import java.util.*;

public class Iteratorr {

    public static void main( String [] args) {
        ArrayList v = new ArrayList ();
        for( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ) {
            v.add ( i );
        }
        System.err.println ( v );
        Iterator i = v.iterator ();
        /*while ( i.hasNext () ) {
            Integer a = ( Integer ) i.next ();
            if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println ( i );
            } else {
                i.remove ();
            }
        }       
        System.out.println ( v );
        */
        while( i.hasNext () ) {
            Integer a = ( Integer) i.next ();
            if ( a % 2 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println ( a );
            } else {
                v.remove ( a );
            }
        }
        System.out.println ( v );
    }
}
```

I know commented code will work properly but **what about non commented code**?  If I try to use `ArrayList#remove(Obj o)`  to remove odd number from `ArrayList` then it is not working. WHY

Comment: `it is not working` is not a valid problem statement. This could mean anything. Doesn't compile? Runtime exception? Unexpected behavior? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Please do read the documentation, carefully for `Iterator`, which clearly states `Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next(). The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.`. So while using `Iterator` always use the `remove ()` method of `Iterator` instead of calling `remove () ` on the list, which can provoke unspecified behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are changing the container in a fashion beyond the knowledge of the iterator.

Consider the `ArrayList`.   It has "n" elements, and a method that returns an iterator (that returns each of the "n" elements in turn).  you could write your own iterator...

```
class MyArrayListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final ArrayList<T> list;
    private int index;

    MyArrayListIterator(ArrayList<T> lst) {
        list = lst;
        index = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < list.size();
    }

    public T next() {
        return list.get(index++);
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Assume the list contains 10, 11, 13, 14

Using this iterator, and removing the odd items directly (not using iterator's remove method):

- 10 is returned; index increases to 1
- 11 is returned; index increases to 2; 11 is removed from list.
- 14 is returned (because list is now "10, 13, 14", and item at index==2 is 14!)

Notice the iterator "skipped" over "13" because the iterator advances each call, and the list shrank moving items to lower indexes.

For the iterator to function properly when the `ArrayList` is modified, the list would have to tell **all** iterators operating on it of the modification (there can be multiple iterators, even without threading).  Or, the iterator itself must make the modification.

Since the `ArrayList` does not store a reference to each active iterator operating on it, the former option is not possible.  Instead, the `ArrayList` maintains a simple state value, which changes when modifications are made to it.  The iterators can check for unexpected changes to the state, and if found, can throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, to warn the programmer that their code is operating on the collection improperly.

Notice the "can check" and "can throw", above.  The iterators are not required to do so; it is a "best effort" check to help the programmer avoid buggy code.

Comment: yes it is working for me.. in the documention of iterator interface while using netbeans just shows that Iterator interface has three methods  1.hasNext(---),2.Next(----)3.remove().......only defination is written here.. how can i see implementation classes of Iterator interface??.. where and how in netbeans ide

Comment: The `Iterator` above is just an example, for illustrating **why** you cannot use the list's `add` and `remove` methods during iteration.  Each collection class has its own iterator implementation, which you cannot replace.  See the source code for the Java collections for the exact implementation details (step into the code with a debugger, if necessary).  But the fact still remains: modifying the collection during iteration can invalid existing iterators.  Use the iterator's remove method to remove elements during iteration.

Comment: See [ArrayList source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html), line 780

Answer (score 0):

The most simple answer is you use if condition to check even / odd number inside the for loop itself , I don't see any need to use iterator .

If it's a must to use iterator then create 2 ArrayLists and fill them upon if condition.

Answer (score -1):

Check out List.listIterator(). The ListIterator interface has a remove() method.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on your answers. This should be a comment.